# i got an error in php xpath scraping Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, xpath, screen-scraping

i am trying to make a simple scrape code for my site but i get and error when i run it

i got this error code

**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object**

this is my code

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}


libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$url = 'https://www.mourjan.com/ae/abu-dhabi/lands';
$amer=get_web_page($url);
$html= $amer['content'];
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $td) {
    if ($td->hasAttribute('onclick')) {
        $links= $td->getAttribute('onclick');
        $links = str_replace("wo('/","",$links);
        $links = str_replace("/')","",$links);

        $url = 'https://www.mourjan.com/ae/abu-dhabi/lands/'.$links.'';
        $amer=get_web_page($url);
        $html= $amer['content'];
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);       
        $name = $xpath->query('*[@id="results"]/div[2]/div[2]/p');
        $phone= $xpath->query('*[@id="results"]/div[2]/div[2]/p/span');
        echo $name->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo '<br />';
        echo str_replace(' ','',$phone->item(0)->nodeValue); 
    }
}
```

**i hope that can someone help me in fixing this issue, i used this xpath because it is helpful better than the other**

regards
Amer

Comment: In which line does the error appear? The only time I see a property-call is in the last line...and that one seems to be correct

Comment: this line (((( echo $name->item(0)->nodeValue; ))))))

Comment: Might I suggest prefixing your XPath expressions with `//`. The way you have them now, your `#results` element would have to be in the root node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the query

```
$name = $xpath->query('*[@id="results"]/div[2]/div[2]/p');
```

has no result. Then you would make here

```
echo $name->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

a call on an empty nodelist (length($name) = 0). Ergo "item(0)" doesn't exist. So the property "nodeValue" cannot be requested.

Comment: FYI, `$name` will **not** be `null` however its `length` property might be `0`

Answer (score 0):

If the Xpath expression returns an empty node list then access `->item(0)` will return `NULL` - hence the error message.

You could use `->length > 0` to validate that here is a node in the list before accessing the item.

Another possibility is using `DOMXpath::evaluate()` and casting the node list into a string in the Xpath expression. An empty list will result in an empty string:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);       
$name = $xpath->evaluate('string(*[@id="results"]/div[2]/div[2]/p)');
$phone = $xpath->evaluate('string(*[@id="results"]/div[2]/div[2]/p/span)');
echo $name;
echo '<br />';
echo str_replace(' ','',$phone);
```